# Does a Pytest Fixture memory reference not change when referenced a second time?

Tags: python, memory, pytest, fixtures

I am writing a program to automate cisco command-line scripting. In the pytest, I made a fixture that returns a Router. The class keeps track of instances to make sure that Routers do not have the same name and throws a ValuError if so. I wanted to make sure that this was the case and used the fixture to make `router` and `router1`which just equals the fixture. I took the `id()` of both and it pointed to the same memory location. Is this a problem with my class design, or is this me not understanding what pytest and/or python do with the memory?

```
class Router(metaclass=IterRouter):
    _all_routers = []
    available_protocols = ['RIP1','RIP2','OSPF1','OSPF2']

    def __init__(self,hostname):
        # If the hostname already exists, then raise a ValueError
        double_list = [hostname == router.hostname for router in self._all_routers]
        if sum(double_list) != 0:
            raise ValueError(f"Router hostname <{hostname}> already exists")
        # Add new router to list of instances.
        Router._all_routers.append(self)
        # Set class instance attributes.
        self.hostname = hostname

@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def default_router():
    name = 'default'
    return Router(name)

def test_invalid_args(self,default_router):
"""Test that if you try and make a second Router with the same name, it will fail."""
   router = default_router
   print(id(router))
   print(router.hostname)
   with pytest.raises(ValueError):
      router1 = default_router
      print(id(router1))
```

The result was that for both `router` and `router1`, I got id `2383405448304` and the test fails saying that the ValueError failed to be raised.

When I switch out the test with instantiating a new Router with the below code, the test passes

```
def test_invalid_args(self,default_router):
"""Test that if you try and make a second Router with the same name, it will fail."""
   router = default_router
   with pytest.raises(ValueError):
      router1 = Router("default")
```

EDIT SOLVED:
I had forgotten about references to a variable being the same after being instantiated. Assigning router_1 to default_router did not instantiate a new default Router variable. I mistakenly forgot that a variable referred to twice is the same thing. The data is loaded in and stays the same as default_router.

Comment: Are you confused as to why `router1 = default_router` doesn't create a new router object?

Comment: That was what I was wondering, I am not sure what I am looking for exactly but I have my suspicions. I want to know why reusing a fixture would not create a different object within the same test.

Comment: Assigning a variable does not create a copy, it creates another reference to to same object. It's not clear what you are expecting

Comment: Then, I think that I am asking why is this the default and how does it come about? The fixture returns a value, but does Pytest automatically reuse the value or it is it Python's default functionality to assign the Router instance to the same memory location?

Comment: I'd be interested to know of a language that doesn't behave like this?

Comment: I know how it worked in Java, just not Python, thanks for having patience. I realize where my mistake was.

Answer (score 0):

A variable assigned to a new name is still a reference to the old variable. I was confused by if each time the variable was referenced a new instance would be created which in retrospect does not make sense.

Assigning router_1 to default_router did not instantiate a new default Router variable. The Router is loaded in and stays the same as default_router during the test.